# How can I connect my node.js express project with mongoDB localhost 27017?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, visual-studio, express

While running the code >>npm start runing successful for few moment and shoing error such as:

```
PS D:\Brototype\Web Development Challenge-2\shopping-cart> npm start
shopping-cart@0.0.0 start nodemon ./bin/www
[nodemon] 3.0.1 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[nodemon] watching path(s): . [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json [nodemon] starting node ./bin/www D:\Brototype\Web Development Challenge-2\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278 const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms, this.description); ^
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Brototype\Web Development Challenge-2\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
Node.js v18.18.0 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

connection.js- [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0bmV.png)    app.js- [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mvoN.png)

I tried to connect my node.js express project with mongodb in VS code terminal. But it's not showing "DB connected" msg on terminal and server not connecting with mongodb url. It showing above error after 5sec .Why?Please help!

My mongosh db version is 2.0.1

Comment: did you fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you're MongoDB server is running or not. This error usually occurs when you do not start the MongoDB server.

Comment: How can I check that? Can u pls hlp me :

Comment: Which OS are you working with?

Comment: Working with Windows 10

Comment: To check if MongoDB is installed correctly, use command `mongod --version`. To run MongoDB server use command `mongod`. To check if server is running, use command `mongo`, this command should connect you to the server. If `mongo` gives error, the server is not running.

Comment: Yeah! mongod --version and  mongod are working. But mongo is not working. It show like "'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually in mine the path is  already added, but the mongo still not working   [C:\Users\user>mongod --version
db version v7.0.2
Build Info: {
    "version": "7.0.2",
    "gitVersion": "02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "windows",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}

C:\Users\user>mongo
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user>
]

Comment: Instead of mongo mongosh working. But how can I connect mongodb with nodejs using mongosh. Is there any way to connect?

Comment: Yes. 'mongo' has been depricated since v5. 'mongosh' is fine.  You can use mongoose to connect to mongo from node.